# PHP - How to access and store the JSON values in variables like $firstName, $lastName

Tags: php, json

I have the output of JSON by `$result = json_encode($json)` in $result. How can i access the values like Mickey, Maddu, mickey@gmail. I need to store these values in variables.

**JSON Output**

```
{"jsonFirstName":"Mickey","jsonLastName":"Maddu","jsonEmail":"mickey@gmail.com","jsonPassword":"QWERqwer!@#$","jsonDob":"2014-01-01","jsonDobTime":"dobtime","jsonLocaldob":"2014-01-01T01:00","jsonSsn":"123-12-1234","jsonPhonenumber":"123-123-1234","jsonCreditcardnumber":"123412341234"}
```

Comment: In javascript? In PHP again? If you are generating the JSON with PHP, why can't you just access the variable in the `$json` array?

Comment: What's the point? You already have that stored in your `$json` variable.

Comment: in php only..i want to store one value in one variable. i think i have to use json_decode()...but no idea on how to use it..

Comment: @jeroen..i want one value in one variable...cld you pls guide me how to do it..

Comment: That's a bit sloppy, you're better off keeping it in an array or an object like you have already. Anyway, `$json['jsonFirstName']` in case of an array or `$json->jsonFirstName` in case of an object (it depends on the type of the `$json` variable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to use `extract()`. (<sup>*Provided that the array stays one-dimensional*</sup>)

```
$json = '{"jsonFirstName":"Mickey","jsonLastName":"Maddu","jsonEmail":"mickey@gmail.com","jsonPassword":"QWERqwer!@#$","jsonDob":"2014-01-01","jsonDobTime":"dobtime","jsonLocaldob":"2014-01-01T01:00","jsonSsn":"123-12-1234","jsonPhonenumber":"123-123-1234","jsonCreditcardnumber":"123412341234"}';

extract(json_decode($json, true));

echo $jsonLastName;
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/202919)

Answer (score 2):

With `json_decode` you can access the JSON as an object or an associative array, looks:

As object:

```
$string = '{"foo": "bar", "foo2": "attr"}';
$the_json = json_decode($string);

echo $the_json->foo;
//output: "bar"
```

As associative array:

```
$string = '{"foo": "bar", "foo2": "attr"}';
$the_json = json_decode($string, true);

echo $the_json['foo'];
//output: "bar"
```

Please, see the oficial documentation: [**PHP JSON**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)